# c++ 2D servos robot arm inverse kinematics

Tags: c++, robotics, mbed, inverse-kinematics

I am currently trying to write code to instruct a robot arm (2 servos motors, 3 sticks) to write out words and am having trouble getting it right. At the moment I am just trying to get it to move to a vector. I think that the inverse kinematics part is correct but all I'm getting is a twitch from one of the motors (if I'm lucky). A Nucleo- F411RE board is being used and I'm using the mbed developer.

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Servo.h"
#include "math.h"

Servo servo1(PA_8), servo2(PA_9);
    float len1 = 9.0;
    float len2 = 7.5;
    double pi = 3.1415926535897;

int lawOfCosines (float a, float b, float c )
{
    return acos((a*a + b*b - c*c) / (2 * a * b));
}
int distance(float x, float y) {
    return sqrt(x*x + y*y);
}

int deg(float rad) {
    return rad * 180 / pi;
}
int main() {

    //fmt.Println("Lets do some tests. First move to (5,5):");
    float x = 5.0;
    float y = 5.0;
    float dist = distance(x, y);
    float D1 = atan2(y, x);
    float D2 = lawOfCosines(dist, len1, len2);
    float A1 = D1 + D2;
    float A2 = lawOfCosines(len1, len2, dist);

   float  m1 = A1 * (100/90); 
   float  m2 = A2 * (100/90);
    for(int i=0; i<m1; i++) {
              servo2 = i/100.0;

              wait(0.01);
          }
    for(int i=0; i<m2; i++) {
               servo1 = i/100.0;              
              wait(0.01);
          }


    }
   `}
```

Any help to where I'm going wrong is greatly appreciated

Comment: `100/90` will always be 1. Change it to `100.0 / 90` Also change return type of `distance`,`deg`,`lawOfCosines`  to `float`

Comment: Thank you @sniper ! I have fixed the return types and changed the for loops to a "servos.write(0)" expression. However still not getting the desired response.

Comment: Change it to`servo1.write(i)` in for loop

Comment: Thanks, i have changed back to the for loop and realised that my inverse kinematics were slightly incorrect. Still not getting the required results although I am not sure why